# Python - Loop through a list of players and make them play a game

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops

So I'm trying to make a game in python where you register players at the start and then can play games of odd or even. I wanted a system where the game would loop over for each player and once ever player within the list has been gone through it opens the menu again.

There is a list named players and the following code just results in an endless loop around the first player. I've tried a few different loops such as a for loop and variants of the while loop but none of them are able to do what I want them to.

This is the code that I have:

```
class OddOrEven(Game):
    def oddoreven():
        index = 0
        print("Hey", players[index], "Odd (o) or Even (e)?")
        choice = input('> \u001b[1m')
        print('\u001b[0m', end='')
        
        randomdice = d.roll()

        while index < len(players):
            while choice != "o" or choice != "e":
                if choice == "o" and randomdice == 1 or randomdice == 3 or randomdice == 5:
                    print("Congratulations,", players[index], "You win!")
                    print()
                elif choice == "o" and randomdice == 2 or randomdice == 4 or randomdice == 6:
                    print("Sorry,", players[index], "You lose!")
                    print()
                elif choice == "e" and randomdice == 2 or randomdice == 4 or randomdice == 6:
                    print("Congratulations,", players[index], "You win!")
                    print()
                elif choice == "e" and randomdice == 1 or randomdice == 3 or randomdice == 5:
                    print("Sorry,", players[index], "You lose!")
                    print()
                else:
                    print("Invalid choice.")
                    choice = input('> \u001b[1m')
                    print('\u001b[0m', end='')
                index += 1
```

Comment: You have an infinite inner while loop.  It is always True.

Comment: @RufusVS I deleted that and still have the same issue, then if I move the index back and or around it just does the work for all the players

Comment: is the `index += 1` indented correctly? it looks like it'd happen after the `while index < len(players):` instead of as the last step inside

Comment: @Tadhg McDonald-Jensen Yeah sorry that was formatting issue when I copied it over

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up fixing it with some tweaking of the code, turns out I had forgotten to add a loop around where the next player would be asked the question so this is what I now have that is working.

```
index = 0
    for index in range(len(players)):
        print("Hey", players[index], "Odd (o) or Even (e)?")
        choice = input('> \u001b[1m')
        print('\u001b[0m', end='')
        
        power = p.getPower()
        randomdice = d.roll()

        # If statement that checks what the power is and adds the value to the random dice so that the new dice can be printed
        if power == 1:
            randomdice + 1
        elif power == 2:
            randomdice + 2
        elif power == 3:
            randomdice + 3
        elif power == 4:
            randomdice + 4
        elif power == 5:
            randomdice + 5

        if randomdice == 1:
            print (dice[0])
        elif randomdice == 2:
            print (dice[1])
        elif randomdice == 3:
            print (dice[2])
        elif randomdice == 4:
            print (dice[3])
        elif randomdice == 5:
            print (dice[4])
        elif randomdice == 6:
            print (dice[5])
        
        while index < len(players):
            if choice == "o" and randomdice == 1 or randomdice == 3 or randomdice == 5:
                print("Congratulations,", players[index], "You win!")
                print()
                break
            elif choice == "o" and randomdice == 2 or randomdice == 4 or randomdice == 6:
                print("Sorry,", players[index], "You lose!")
                print()
                break
            elif choice == "e" and randomdice == 2 or randomdice == 4 or randomdice == 6:
                print("Congratulations,", players[index], "You win!")
                print()
                break
            elif choice == "e" and randomdice == 1 or randomdice == 3 or randomdice == 5:
                print("Sorry,", players[index], "You lose!")
                print()
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid choice.")
                print("Odd (o) or Even (e)?")
                choice = input('> \u001b[1m')
                print('\u001b[0m', end='')
        index += 1
```